Getting "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException" while trying to connect to amazon redshift driver
Below is the POM dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

Database connection code contains in below path
src -> main -> utils -> DatabaseConnection.java
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnection {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class);
    Connection connection = null;
   Properties props  = new Properties();

    public  void getDataBaseConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
            logger.info("Connecting to database...");
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:redshift://endpoint:port/dbname";
            String dbUsername = "username";
            String dbPassword = "password";
            jdbcUrl = jdbcUrl + "?AccessKeyID=" + dbUsername + "&SecretAccessKey=" + dbPassword
                    + "&DbUser=admin&ssl=true&tcpKeepAlive=true";
            props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
            props.setProperty("user", dbUsername);
            props.setProperty("password", dbPassword);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, props);
            if (connection != null) {
                logger.info("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                logger.info("Failed to make connection!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}


And calling the above code in below path in testng file
src -> test -> java -> tests -> name -> sample_test.java
import utils.DatabaseConnection;
public class sample_test extends TestBase {

    DatabaseConnection dbconn  = new DatabaseConnection();

@Test
public void db_test(){
        dbconn.getDataBaseConnection();
    }
}


after executing above I am getting below error
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Exception in provider
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.assertNoException (SurefirePlugin.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:892)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1010)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException:
Cannot instantiate class tests.name.sample_test
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance (InstanceCreator.java:41)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance (ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense (GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance (ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances (ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances (TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances (TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init (TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init> (TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods (TestRunner.java:465)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init> (TestRunner.java:176)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner (SuiteRunner.java:635)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init (SuiteRunner.java:221)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init> (SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner (TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners (TestNG.java:1314)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally (TestNG.java:1160)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites (TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run (TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run (TestNGExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke (TestNGProvider.java:147)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2 (ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke (ProviderFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider (ProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1010)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance (InstanceCreator.java:38)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance (ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense (GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance (ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances (ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances (TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances (TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init (TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init> (TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods (TestRunner.java:465)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init> (TestRunner.java:176)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner (SuiteRunner.java:635)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init (SuiteRunner.java:221)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init> (SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner (TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners (TestNG.java:1314)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally (TestNG.java:1160)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites (TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run (TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run (TestNGExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke (TestNGProvider.java:147)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2 (ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke (ProviderFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider (ProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1010)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at tests.name.sample_test.<init> (sample_test.java:30)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance (InstanceCreator.java:38)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance (ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense (GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance (ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances (ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances (TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances (TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init (TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init> (TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods (TestRunner.java:465)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init> (TestRunner.java:176)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner (SuiteRunner.java:635)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init (SuiteRunner.java:221)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init> (SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner (TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners (TestNG.java:1314)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally (TestNG.java:1160)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites (TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run (TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run (TestNGExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke (TestNGProvider.java:147)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2 (ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke (ProviderFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider (ProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1010)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatedClassLoader.java:97)
    at tests.name.sample_test.<init> (sample_test.java:30)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance (InstanceCreator.java:38)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance (ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense (SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense (GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance (ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances (ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances (TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances (TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init (TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init> (TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods (TestRunner.java:465)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init (TestRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init> (TestRunner.java:176)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner (SuiteRunner.java:635)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init (SuiteRunner.java:221)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init> (SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner (TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners (TestNG.java:1314)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally (TestNG.java:1160)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites (TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run (TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run (TestNGExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke (TestNGProvider.java:147)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2 (ReflectionUtils.java:202))


Note : Code works fine if I execute with main() method. But it fails when run with above configuration.
It should connect with database

Your JDBC url looks wrong, and you never included the actual values for the endpoint, port, or database name.  Please refer to the docs for more information.

@TimBiegeleisen this is jdbc url "jdbc:redshift://01659-prod-db-redshift.698451230654.eu-west-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com:5439/lakehouse"

WHy not use the Java Redshift Data Client?

@onkar which IDE are you using? is it intellij?

@ApostolosEmmanouilidis yes it is intellij.

@smac2020 we already have implementation for this. Just reusing the same

Interesting.  I have never had an issue when using Redshift Data Client.

The issue has been resolved by changing the surefire plugin version from 2.19.1 to 3.2.5. My guess is it is resolve because of dynamically loading classpath which happens in latest version of surefire plugin and not in the older version.
